# Tikhonov Regularization Alternate Formulation

Tags: linear-algebra

> ## 2.2 Tikhonov Reqularization
>
> Tikhonov regularization, named for **Russian mathematician Andrey Tikhonov**, attempts to fix the issue that arises when the least squares method is used with an ill-posed inverse problem **by adding an additional constraint on the minimization:**
>   $$\min_x\{\Vert Ax-b \Vert ^2_2 + \lambda^2\Vert x\Vert^2_2\}$$
>   In the new minimization, the additional constraint is the squared norm of $x.$ **$\lambda$ is a non-negative constant decided in advance, acting as a weight on the strength of the additional constraint.** Some alternate ways to write Tikhonov regularization include
>   $$\bbox[lightgreen]{(A^T A + \lambda^2 I)x=A^{T}b}$$
>   and
>   $$\min \left\Vert\genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{}{A}{\lambda I}x - \genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{}{b}{0}\right\Vert$$

Can someone explain the alternate formulation in green. I am not able to convert this formulation to standard one. I get one Atransposedinverse extra. The second formulation can be easily converted to original formulation, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expand the term to be minimized, take the derivative with respect to $x$ and set it equal to zero:

$$\begin{align}||Ax-b||_2^2+\lambda^2||x||_2^2&=(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)+\lambda^2x^Tx\\&=x^TA^TAx-2b^TAx+b^Tb+\lambda^2x^Tx\tag{1}\end{align}$$

Taking the derivative w.r.t. $x$ and setting it equal to zero gives

$$2A^TAx-2A^Tb+2\lambda^2x=0\tag{2}$$

from which the given equation follows.

Comment: I didn't notice that there is no min in that formulation unlike others, so effectively it was closed form solution. Thanks Matt.